# fancybox shows only one picture in group

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Please see the code below.. fansybox some reason only shows one picture - the first. And the second picture does not show. I don't understand why.

I read the tutorial and at first I tried to use this code http://jsfiddle.net/2k8EP/ but this code not working with ajax and jquery.infinitescroll plugin, the fancybox work only for pictures which were loaded on the first page and not working for other dynamically loaded pages.
My code excellent work with jquery.infinitescroll plugin but with one trouble: fancy doesn't show second picture. 
I need the code like this jsfiddle.net/2k8EP/ which correctly works with jquery.infinitescroll plug-in.
Sorry for my english.
Thnx!

p.s. [jsfiddle.net/sxJgQ](http://jsfiddle.net/sxJgQ/) example code of my problem

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="images/cards/img_1370603520.jpg"><img  src="images/cards/img_1370603520.jpg" width="200" height="125" border=0></a>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".open_fancybox").fancybox([{
            href : 'images/cards/img_1370603520.jpg',                
            title : 'title1'
        },
    {
            href : 'images/cards/img_1370603521.jpg',                
            title : 'title2'
        },
    ], {
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
            }
    },
        padding : 0,
    loop: false
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand from your question what do you exactly want to achieve. Please read tutorials first, it's all included there - for instance here:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

But if you want some examples, I made a fiddle you can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/9tagE/. It's a simple solution, which will open one image on click from another. But if you want a gallery with two different pictures you need to do it like this:

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4058/4252054277_f0fa91e026.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4058/4252054277_f0fa91e026_m.jpg"/>
</a>
 <a class="open_fancybox" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2489/4234944202_0fe7930011.jpg">
     <img  src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2489/4234944202_0fe7930011_m.jpg"/>
</a>
```

You can check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eFPbe/

**IMPORTANT:**

Remember to include all files:

1. jquery.fancybox.js
2. jquery.fancybox.css
3. jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css
4. jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js

**EDIT**: Here you can check an example of probably what you tried to do (create gallery from one image) http://jsfiddle.net/2k8EP/

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {

    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
            title : 'manual 1st title'
        },
        {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
            title : '2nd title'
        },
        {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
            title : '3rd title'
        }
    ], {
        nextEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect : 'none',
        padding    : 0,
        helpers    : {
            title : {
                type: 'over'  
            },
            thumbs : {
                width  : 75,
                height : 50,
                source : function( item ) {
                    return item.href.replace('_b.jpg', '_s.jpg');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I added more detail in my first question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your problem. You need to tell me what have you tried already, attach some more code. I don't see in your code any usage of the plugin you mentioned. What exactly you want to achieve with this plugin?

Comment: I want to understand my mistake and fix the code to open two images through fancybox. Now when I click on the link I see only one picture  'images/cards/img_1370603520.jpg' without next\prev arrows and can't switch to the second image 'images/cards/img_1370603521.jpg'